# Is there any numerical reason for not using repeated multiplication instead of integer powers?

Tags: matlab

I recently discovered that, in MATLAB 2013b at least, it is significantly faster to do repeated multiplication rather than integer powers.  That is,

```
tic;test4p = a.^4;toc
```

is much slower than

```
tic;test4m = a.*a.*a.*a;toc
```

See http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5377 for full details.  Is there any numerical reason (accuracy etc) why repeated multiplication might be a bad idea?

Comment: Are you sure that matlab is using integer powers? If you try with a biger number (20) test4p is taking amost the same time but test4m is taking much more than before.

Comment: What happens if you try a.^3.14 ?  If MATLAB is using a general purpose exponentiation routine (e.g. by using log() and exp()), then it should take the same time as a.^4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that MATLAB does not do [exponentiation-by-squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for positive integer powers, since that algorithm should require fewer multiplications. I think a consequence of that should be that numerical errors accumulate less quickly.

[Optimal addition-chain multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) of exponents is an NP-complete problem, so it's not worth it to figure out the sequence of multiplies and exponentiations that minimizes the total number of multiplicative operations.

Answer (score 6):

the numeric reason would be the loss precision. at each multiplication you lose a little bit of precision. If you want to implement power by multiplication, then it's better to look up the algorithm. I once coded the algorithm from Stepanov's "Elements of Programming" book, it's the fastest possible way.

UPDATE: I found the earlier version of Stepanov's book as [Notes](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gsd/notes-on-programming-2006-10-13.pdf)

Search for fast_power algorithm in section 10.3. It's so beautiful, one of the most elegant pieces of code ever

Comment: His algorithm is essentially exponentiation by squaring with some additional implementation-level optimizations.

Comment: Yes. It's much faster than the stock algorithm. I had an accounting application where the powers were always integer numbers, so it worked fine for me.